# Django navigator.sendbeacon csrf protection

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have a problem with `navigator.sendBeacon('endpoint/', data)`. I have an error Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) because it pass data via POST method. I know i should set csrf token, but I don't know how set it in this case, anyone have any idea how it should be done? I'm using Django==2.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
var data = new FormData();        
data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{csrf_token}}');
navigator.sendBeacon('endpoint/',data)
```

If it's a js file, then in your html you should create a variable like

```
<script>
    var csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>
```

Then you can use it when you append like this:

```
data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken);
```